# shorten if statement code adding last days of month as offset column

Tags: excel, vba

just wondering if anybody has an idea to shorten the two if statement in the middle of the code, what the code does is find the sheet named in (A2 of sheet DC) then get the month of (B4 of sheet DC) then find the starting date of the month in sheet named in (A2 of sheet DC) which is targetsht Range("F4:NF4"),then using the offset line find a value of 1 then if true copy name in same row column C of targetsht, the addpm variable is an additional offset column since the dates are sequential Jan 1 to Dec 31 Range("F4:NF4")

```
Sub POS()
Dim shtDC As Worksheet: Set shtDC = Worksheets("DC")
Dim pname As String, targetsht As String
Dim lrwsht As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim targetDate As Date
Dim searchRange As Range, cell As Range, cellc As Range
Dim lastDOM As Integer, sdate, addpm, cy
Dim lastJan, lastFeb, lastMar, lastApr, lastMay, lastJun
Dim lastJul, lastAug, lastSep, lastOct, lastNov

targetsht = shtDC.Range("A2")
cy = "2023" 'change year accordingly
    'clear names
    shtDC.Range("B7:H7,B9:H9,B11:H11,B13:H13,B15:H15,B17:H17").ClearContents
    'Set targetDate value - the month to loop
    If Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Jan" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-01-01")
        addpm = 0
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Feb" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-02-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Mar" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-03-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Apr" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-04-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "May" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-05-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Jun" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-06-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Jul" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-07-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Aug" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-08-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Sep" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-09-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Oct" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-10-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Nov" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-11-01")
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Dec" Then
        targetDate = DateValue(cy & "-12-01")
    End If

        'set additional offset column - Feb to Dec
    If Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Feb" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Mar" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Apr" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "May" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Jun" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        lastMay = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-05-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr + lastMay
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Jul" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        lastMay = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-05-01"), 0))
        lastJun = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-06-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr + lastMay + lastJun
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Aug" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        lastMay = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-05-01"), 0))
        lastJun = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-06-01"), 0))
        lastJul = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-07-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr + lastMay + lastJun + lastJul
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Sep" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        lastMay = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-05-01"), 0))
        lastJun = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-06-01"), 0))
        lastJul = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-07-01"), 0))
        lastAug = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-08-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr + lastMay + lastJun + lastJul + lastAug
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Oct" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        lastMay = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-05-01"), 0))
        lastJun = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-06-01"), 0))
        lastJul = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-07-01"), 0))
        lastAug = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-08-01"), 0))
        lastSep = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-09-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr + lastMay + lastJun + lastJul + lastAug + lastSep
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Nov" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        lastMay = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-05-01"), 0))
        lastJun = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-06-01"), 0))
        lastJul = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-07-01"), 0))
        lastAug = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-08-01"), 0))
        lastSep = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-09-01"), 0))
        lastOct = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-10-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr + lastMay + lastJun + lastJul + lastAug + lastSep + lastOct
    ElseIf Left(shtDC.Range("B4"), 3) = "Dec" Then
        lastJan = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-01-01"), 0))
        lastFeb = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-02-01"), 0))
        lastMar = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-03-01"), 0))
        lastApr = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-04-01"), 0))
        lastMay = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-05-01"), 0))
        lastJun = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-06-01"), 0))
        lastJul = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-07-01"), 0))
        lastAug = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-08-01"), 0))
        lastSep = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-09-01"), 0))
        lastOct = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-10-01"), 0))
        lastNov = Day(Application.EoMonth(DateValue(cy & "-11-01"), 0))
        addpm = lastJan + lastFeb + lastMar + lastApr + lastMay + lastJun + lastJul + lastAug + lastSep + lastOct + lastNov
    End If

    'Find targetDate
    Set searchRange = Worksheets(targetsht).Range("F4:NF4")
    For Each cell In searchRange
            If DateValue(cell) = targetDate Then
                lrwsht = Worksheets(targetsht).Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row - 4
                lastDOM = Day(Application.EoMonth(cell, 0)) - 1
                'loop thru days of the month
                For i = 0 To lastDOM
                    sdate = cell.Offset(0, i) 'date to search in dc sheet
                    pname = ""
                    'loop thru names
                    For j = 3 To lrwsht
                        If cell.Offset(j, i) = 1 Then
                            pname = pname & "-" & cell.Offset(j, -3 + (addpm * -1))
                        End If
                    Next j
                    'copy names to dc sheet
                    If pname <> "" Then
                        Set searchRange = shtDC.Range("B6:H16")
                        For Each cellc In searchRange
                            If cellc = sdate Then
                                cellc.Offset(1, 0) = Mid(pname, 2)
                            End If
                        Next cellc
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: If addpm calc is for this `cell.Offset(j, -3 + (addpm * -1)` to refer to Column C then `cell.Offset(0, 3 - cell.Column)` will do the same.

Comment: Are the dates on DC in "B6:H16" a calendar layout with week day columns Sun to Sat

Comment: @CDP1802 yes it is a calendar layout columns Mon to Sun

Comment: tested and works  `pname = pname & "-" & cell.Offset(j, 3 - cell.Column)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub POS()

    Dim wb As Workbook, shtDC As Worksheet, shtTarget As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range, col As Range
    Dim cy As Double, mth As String, n As Long
    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, dt As Date, ar(1 To 31) As String
    Dim lastrow As Long, r As Long, c As Long, d As Long
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set shtDC = wb.Sheets("DC")
    With shtDC
        'clear names
        .Range("B7:H7,B9:H9,B11:H11,B13:H13,B15:H15,B17:H17").ClearContents
         Set shtTarget = wb.Sheets(.Range("A2").Value)
         mth = Left(.Range("B4"), 3)
    End With
    
    'the month to loop
    cy = Year(Date) '"2023" 'change year accordingly
    dtStart = DateValue(cy & "-" & mth & "-01")
    dtEnd = DateAdd("m", 1, dtStart) - 1
       
    'Find StartDate
    With shtTarget
        Set col = .Range("F4").Offset(0, DateDiff("d", DateSerial(cy, 1, 1), dtStart))
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        d = 1
        For dt = dtStart To dtEnd
           If col <> dt Then
               MsgBox "Date error at " & col.Address & " not " & dt, vbCritical
               Exit Sub
           End If
           
           ' scan down adding names to array
           c = col.Column
           For r = 3 To lastrow - 4
               If .Cells(r, c) = 1 Then
                  ar(d) = ar(d) & "-" & .Cells(r, "C")
               End If
           Next
           
           d = d + 1
           Set col = col.Offset(, 1)
        Next
    End With
    
    'update DC sheet
    With Sheets("DC")
        Set rng = .Range("B6:H16")
        For d = 1 To 31
            If ar(d) <> "" Then
                dt = dtStart + d - 1
                Set cel = rng.Find(Format(dt, "d-mmm-yy"), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
                If cel Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox Format(dt, "d-mmm-yy") & _
                    " not found in " & rng.Address, vbExclamation
                Else
                    cel.Offset(1) = Mid(ar(d), 2) ' remove -
                    n = n + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " days updated" & vbLf & dtStart _
           & " - " & dtEnd, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the code, tried but it cant find the date in `Set col = .Range("F4:NF4").Find(dtStart, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)` so msgbox triggers could not locate column, tried using `DateValue(col)` but it just errors out

Comment: tried using `dtStart = Format(DateValue(cy & "-" & mth & "-01"), "d-mmm-yy")` where the d-mmm-yy is the format of range F4:NF4 but still cant find it

Comment: @k1dr0ck what is your date format in Windows regional settings ?

Comment: my windows regional date setting is m/dd/yyyy

Comment: @k1dr0ck see update, I changed the find for a calculation of the column using datediff. The find for B6:H16 I formatted search value to d-mmm-yy which I assumed is the display format.